# Cocoa read/write a file

Tags: xcode, cocoa, file

How do I write to a txt file, so I would like a string value inside the document which I later want to read.

What I want to do is basically just a demo app, I want a specific piece of text in a NSTextField to be written into a file and then be read from the file and the contents of the file to be placed in a second NSTextField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSString's `-writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` or `-writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:` methods to write your string to a file. There are plenty of other ways, but these are about as easy as it gets. There are corresponding methods for reading a file into a string.

Comment: Thanks :), I figured it out, I dunno what I was doing wrong before but hey now it works :)